# HEAD tags interfering with base64 in PhoneGap ??? Even when nothing is in the Head? base 64

Tags: javascript, html, base64, phonegap, head

This is the strangest programming issue I've ever come across... I'm working on a program that uses some audio encoded as base64.  They are small audio files (less than 2k each) Here's a simplified version.  If you run this exactly as is in your browser, you'll see a button that plays a click sound when pressed. GET READY FOR THE CRAZY PART....  I put this into phonegap and it didn't work... UNLESS I remove the two head tags `<head>` and `</head>`  Try it, put the code into an html file called index.html and try it in phonegap.  You'll see the button, but it won't play. But if you try it without the head tags it will play the click sound.  Someone please explain!

```js
function snd(s) {
aud = new Audio(); 
aud.src = document.getElementById(s).src; 
aud.load();
aud.volume=1;
aud.play(); 
}
```

```css
button {width:200px;height:60px;margin:20px}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<audio id="click" src="data:audio/mp3;base64,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"></audio>

<button onclick="snd('click')">click</button><br><br>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a follow-up to this, I wanted to use a base64 font in my project as well. It wasn't working in phonegap.  I assumed phonegap just had some kind of problem with base64.  I just tried the base64 font again without the head tags... AND IT WORKED!   Why are head tags having this effect on base64 in phonegap?

Comment: Another follow-up... I also have base64 images in my project.  Those DO work in phonegap with the head tags or without the head tags.  That makes it even more difficult to understand.  Why are only base64 audio and fonts effected by the head tags.  So Weird !